# Does jQuery .html() manipulate DOM?

Tags: jquery, dom, dom-manipulation

I am running the following function:

```
    $(function () {
    var tbl = $('table[id^="stg_"]');
    var tmpl = tbl.attr('id').replace('stg_', '');

    // how many elements before
    console.log($(":input, select").length);

    $.get('templates/' + tmpl + '.html', function (data) {
        tbl.html(data);
    });

    // same number after ?
    console.log($(":input, select").length);
});
```

However, it doesn't appear as if jQuery is modifying the DOM since I am getting the same `.length` on my `":input, select"` selector before and after setting the html of my table.

This is just a test, but I am curious if anyone has ever tried this or has any idea why the length would be the same after setting the .html of the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.get` is asynchronous, the second log shows the same number because it is logged before the ajax is completed, try

```
console.log($(":input, select").length);
$.get('templates/' + tmpl + '.html', function (data) {
    tbl.html(data);
    console.log($(":input, select").length);//probably it will give a different number
});
```

or in your current scenario set `async:false` *(which is highly not recommended)*

```
$(function () {
    $.ajaxSetup({
       async:false
    });
    var tbl = $('table[id^="stg_"]');
    var tmpl = tbl.attr('id').replace('stg_', '');

    // how many elements before
    console.log($(":input, select").length);

    $.get('templates/' + tmpl + '.html', function (data) {
        tbl.html(data);
    });   

    console.log($(":input, select").length);
});
```

Comment: That's exactly it! Thank you very much. I will mark this as the answer in 10 minutes :)

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
$.get('templates/' + tmpl + '.html', function (data) {
    tbl.html(data);
    console.log($(":input, select").length);
});
```

You are making an asynchronous request and printing the number of elements before the ajax request is completed. So try printing the count inside your callback which is executed asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

`$.get` is asycnchronous - it fires off its request and the code continues to run. As a result, `console.log($(":input, select").length);` is executed before the `$get` returns. Add `console.log($(":input, select").length);` to the callback (after `tbl.html(data)`) and you will see better results.

Answer (score 0):

you are first reporting the length and only then manipulating dom ;). What @Nemoy and @3nigma said.